# Get the sdcard image in gridview and show the selected image in another activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I need to get the images from SD card and show it into a grid view and display the selected image into a image view.How it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly create this intent and start the activity for result:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
 startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

then in the activity for results handle like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       pickedImageUri = data.getData();
       imgView.setImageUri(pickedImageUri);

}
```

You must make sure you reference imgView to a layout id by stating:

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_pickedpicture);
```

I hope this helps.